# Aggregated values in dimple.js for Y axis

Tags: javascript, csv, graph, dimple.js

I am using dimple.js to draw the graph, I read an excel file and put data in a .tsv file from where I read the stuff.

Data in file looks like this

```
country count   site
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his dom
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his IP 
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his dom
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his dom
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his IP 
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his dom
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his dom
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his dom
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his dom
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his dom
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his IP 
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his IP 
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his dom
zeustracker.abuse.ch    1   his dom
rules.emergingthreats.net   1   NORT Ru
rules.emergingthreats.net   1   NORT Ru
rules.emergingthreats.net   1   NORT Ru
rules.emergingthreats.net   1   NORT Ru
```

but the graph it is showing looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVFTs.gif)

here is the code ,

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 400);
    d3.tsv("<?=$tsv_file;?>", function (data) {
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(80, 30, 510, 305)
      var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "country");
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "count");
      myChart.addSeries(["site"], dimple.plot.bar);
      myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
```

The problem is that it is showing 14K on y-axis which doesn't make any sense, the Y-axis should have 9 entries and 3 for other, Am I doing something wrong ?